# Trying to read login name from Active Directory returning null

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

```
DirectoryEntry DirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.None);

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(DirEntry);
search.Filter = String.Format("(SAMAccountName={0})", "my_login_name");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
SearchResult result1 = search.FindOne();

myDataTable Users = new myDataTable();
DataRow User;

foreach (SearchResult i in search.FindAll())
{
    DirectoryEntry CurrentDirEntry;
    User = Users.NewUserRow();

    CurrentDirEntry = i.GetDirectoryEntry();
    User.FirstName = (string)CurrentDirEntry.Properties["givenname"].Value;
    User.LastName = (string)CurrentDirEntry.Properties["sn"].Value;
    User.UserName = (string)CurrentDirEntry.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value;
    User.Email = (string)CurrentDirEntry.Properties["mail"].Value;
    Users.AddUserRow(User);
}
```

I'm trying to read some properties from active directory but the value for

> sAMAccountName

is always returned as null, i'm wondering why this is so since its being matched in the search filter. Could it be related to access privileges?

I want to return the FirstName, LastName, Email and login Name. I'm getting other properties except login name.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, my_login_name);

    if(user != null)
    {
       // do something here....     
       string samAccountName = user.SamAccountName;
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

**Update:** if you need to search by fields that aren't handled by the `.FindByIdentity()` call, then you need to use the `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
   // and with the first name (GivenName) of "Bruce" and a last name (Surname) of "Miller"
   UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
   qbeUser.GivenName = "Bruce";
   qbeUser.Surname = "Miller";

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement recommendation. What would be the most effiecient way of searching by either FirstName, LastName or Email?

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior: updated my question - if you need to search by other fields, use the `PrincipalSearcher` which allows you to define a "query-by-example" approach to searching

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the spacing in ["sAMAccountName "] of :

```
User.UserName = (string)CurrentDirEntry.Properties["sAMAccountName "].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one , I used it before**

**VB**

```
    Dim myDe As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DOMAIN.LOCAL")
    Dim deSearcher As New DirectorySearcher(myDe)
    Dim userDE As DirectoryEntry
    Dim email As String = ""

    Try
        deSearcher.Filter = "(&(sAMAccountName=" & UserName & "))"
        userDE = deSearcher.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry()
        email = userDE.Properties("mail").Value

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

**C#**

```
    DirectoryEntry myDe = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DOMAIN.LOCAL");
    DirectorySearcher deSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(myDe);
    DirectoryEntry userDE = default(DirectoryEntry);
    string email = "";

    try {
        deSearcher.Filter = "(&(sAMAccountName=" + UserName + "))";
        userDE = deSearcher.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry();
        email = userDE.Properties("mail").Value;
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how C# handles it but I've seen LDAP-libs returning attribute names all in lower case. So it might help to simply call for `samaccountname` instead of `sAMAccountName`.